# Jumping off a boat vs ship

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Why it is harder to jump towards the coast in a boat than in a ship (more massive than the boat) that is equally near as the boat? I think we should use Newton Law's and this happens because the mass of the ship is bigger than the boat. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

When you push off, as you go forwards, the boat moves backwards. Momentum is conserved, so that your mass$\times$velocity equals the boat's mass$\times$ the boat's velocity.

If you do the sums you will see that if you and the boat have comparable masses then the boat moves backwards quite quickly. Because you exert the force for your leap over a small, but finite time, this gives the boat time to move further away from whatever it is you're trying to jump on.

But a ship is far more massive than you. So its velocity backward is completely negligible.